# ERROR InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 and I have one form field which does not require any authentication that means even non-users can fill up the form and submit. But now I am getting an error when I press submit button when I logout and fill the form

```
ERROR InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified
```

I have removed AuthGuard from that specific route but it throws this error. any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: submitting triggers a http request?

Comment: yes it is using post request

Comment: do you have an interceptor in your app?

Comment: yes.
 `intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
    const authRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
    });
    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }`

Comment: can anyone explain this? I am still stuck

Comment: sorry, i got busy. The interceptor is the one creating the issue. I'm going to try to post a solution for you in the answers section

Answer (score 0):

interceptor is the one creating the problem. Because it intercepts all http calls, and injects a token before nexting it.

```
intercept( req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
   const authToken = this.authService.getToken(); 
   const authRequest = req.clone({ 
      headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken) 
   }); 

   return next.handle(authRequest); 
}
```

as you can see. it gets a token from service, then injects the bearer token in the headers, and then nexts this.

this happens because you are trying to get a token that doesn't exist on logout (in this line):

```
const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
```

solution? add an if to the statement of the type:

```
const authRequest = authToken ? req.clone({ ..what you got }) : req;
```

if this doesn't work we start debugging your service (authService), idk what that getToken does. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: it didn't work and threw the same error along with `core.js:1673 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: getToken gets token from auth service `eyJhbGciOiKIUzI1aiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9` when user is logged in

Comment: is getToken another http call?

Comment: I have updated my question and added auth-service.ts